# Save as project

Tags: c#, wpf, save

How can I store (save) a variable, so that i can use it after I close and run the program again? I can't use saveFileDialog cause it is 2D array. Other programs have their own extension. Can I make my own extension, too? Something like "Save project as...".

Comment: Just in case you didn't know (because you asked about 'making' an extension), file extensions are only _indicators_ of the format used so that windows explorer has an easier time opening it and you can actually name them whatever you want. If I remember correctly, Adobe's .AI format is a PDF. It's sometimes useful to give a file your own extension just to associate it with your program, even if it's really only a text file or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save some object to the disk, you either need to devise some file format for your data, or use one of the existing, generic ones.

In .Net, probably the simplest way is to use [the binary formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) to do this:

```
void Save(SomeType obj, string fileName)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
    }
}
```

The `obj` object and all objects it references have to be serializable. Most primitive types already are serializable and you can make your own types serializable by using [the `[Serializable]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx).

The `Load()` method would be similar, except it would use `File.OpenRead()` and `formatter.Deserialize()`.

How to choose the file name is up to you, but you certainly can use `SaveFileDialog` for that.

Answer (score 1):

There are different sirialization types available in `.NET`. Every of them has its pros and cons. So you should pick-up that one most suitable for your needs. 
It worth to take a time and to get at least a general overview of those ones.

For example:

The most common approach is binary serialization (offered by svick), it fast and has low memory footprint, but it's definitely less flexible then others in terms of scalability. Cause
standart `.NET` serialization saves type information too, which leads to tough coupling with the actually *type* saved and not only data.

In one anwer it's difficult to explain everything, so I suggest you to look here

[Serialization and Types of Serialization in .Net](http://mr-ponna.com/Article/23/Serialization-and-Types-of-Serialization-in-Net/)

Good luck

Comment: And those are not the only possible serialization formats. You could also use some external library, to serialize the object into JSON or Protocol Buffers. And there are probably many other formats I haven't heard of.

Comment: Sure, those ones are built- in ones + you have all other 3rd part libs.